# get id from list of elements with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've the next HTML code and I would  to get the id attribute from a HTML list( id="seconde") whith jquery.

```
     <div id="navigation">
<ul    class=" sf-menu sf-vertical " >
            <li >

                <a href="#">Pollo</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Prime lavorazioni</a>

                    </li>
                    <li id = "seconde">
                        <a href="#">Seconde lavorazioni</a>

                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Terze lavorazioni</a>

                    </li>

                </ul>
            </li>



        </ul>
        </div>
```

Thi is my .js:

```
    $("ul.sf-menu li ").click(function(){

          var oID = $(this).attr("id");
          alert(oID);
        });
```

but doesn't work. any idea? thanks

Comment: What exactly doesn't works? Are you confised with two alert messages?

Comment: inside the alert don't show the messagge with li ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that your list is nested. You have a DOM tree of ul.sf-menu > li > ul > li

So when you click on a list item, your callback actually fires twice because two list items have been clicked.

You might consider changing your code to this, so only list items are matched that are children of an ul:

```
$("ul.sf-menu ul > li ").click(function(){

      var oID = $(this).attr("id");
      alert(oID);
});
```

Alternatively, you might remove the id from the li-items and add them rather to the links itself.

Answer (score 0):

You should only attach event handlers to the inner li tags (and make sure that oID variable is defined because some of the li tags don't have 'id' attributes):

```
$("ul.sf-menu ul li ").click(function()
{
  var oID = $(this).attr("id");
  if ( oID )
    alert(oID);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("ul.sf-menu ul li ").click(function(){
    var oID = $(this).attr("id");

    if(typeof oID != 'undefined'){
        alert(oID);
    }
});​
```

Find the target(DOM tree) LI and I just validate for undefined too

http://jsfiddle.net/sameerast/8YwVj/

Answer (score 0):

When you click on a list item, your callback actually fires twice because two list items have been clicked. You given id only in second LI Items. Please ID in every LI elements and try below code.

You have a DOM tree of ul.sf-menu > li > ul > li.

You can Use

$("ul.sf-menu ul > li ").click(function(){

```
  var oID = $(this).attr("id");
  alert(oID);
```

});